# Could a sqlite3 db be corrupted by 3rd party software?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

We have two Rails 3.2 apps using SQLite3 (gem `sqlite3 1.3.7`) hosted on Ubuntu 12.04 server. Both the OS and database are on the same disk (AWS EBS)

One has never had problem with sqlite3. Another one has 2 `complete lock-out` (need to reboot) and one `file corruption` so far last year.

The user load for those 2 apps are minor. We don't quite understand how this has happened. The only difference is that the 2nd rails app has a 3rd party program to upload bunch of records into the app and we suspect this 3rd party software did something bad to the sqlite3.

We have no info about how the 3rd party software was designed and developed. Its sole use is to upload some spreadsheet data into the app and app saves them into table.

Our question is whether sqlite3 is easily corrupted by 3rd party software?

If it is, how to prevent sqlite3 from being corrupt by 3rd party software and/or specify additional requirements for the 3rd party software developer to prevent the software from corrupting SQLite.

(Follow-up from https://stackoverflow.com/q/16797362/398670)

Comment: Repost of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16797362/398670 with some info added. See the comments on the prior question for some extra context. (I think this repost is perfectly fine, I'm just making sure the history is accessible for anyone else looking for info on this).

Comment: Obvious questions: They're hosted on "Ubuntu". Which ubuntu? Are both on the same server with the same disks, filesystem, etc? Or are they on the same server on the same file system and disk array? What is the "third party software" in question?

Comment: Also, seriously, what's your SQLite version? You're asking about possible corruption and not giving the exact version of the database software having the problem. The SQLite gem for rails is not SQLite its self, you need to give the SQLite library version.

Comment: sqlite3 1.3.7 works with sqlite3 3.6.16 or above according to the description. However I am having hard time to find the exact version of sqlite3 on ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mismatched locking protocols?

Section 2.3 of [the SQLite FAQ on corruption](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html) seems like a likely candidate:

> 2.3 Two processes using different locking protocols
>
> The default locking mechanism used by SQLite on unix platforms is
>   POSIX advisory locking, but there are other options. By selecting an
>   alternative sqlite3_vfs using the sqlite3_open_v2() interface [...].
>
> ...
>
> It is important that all connections to the same database file use the same locking protocol. [...] ... **possibly leading to database corruption.**.

In your position I'd run the mystery "3rd party software" under `strace` or (more detailed) `ltrace` to see what it was doing in detail if I couldn't get the info I needed from detailed SQLite logging.

### Unsafe file manipulation

Another possibility is that the 3rd party app is being "clever" and doing some kind of copy, update, swap trick that's safe for normal files but guarantees serious corruption of an open database. Again, you'll be able to see this in `strace` output. Be prepared to do some learning in the process of analysing the strace output, though...

### Mismatched versions

If the 3rd party app embeds a different SQLite database engine version you might be seeing issues caused by mismatched versions. See in particular the FAQ entry on 3.7.0 vs 3.6.x:

> [7.5 Corruption following alternating writes from 3.6 and 3.7.](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html)

Comment: If the 3rd party software just acts as a html browser interacting with the rails app to upload record, what it can do to corrupt sqlite3?

Comment: @user938363 Is that some kind of hypothetical question, or are you giving us another hint about what they mystery "3rd party software" actually is/does? Either way: it can't, really, you've got hardware issues, an SQLite bug, or something else on the machine is causing the issue.

Comment: This was the only requirement we gave to the 3rd party developer to make the software mimicing a browser. But we don't have the info if the software was actually developed behaving as browser.

Comment: @user938363 Time for software reverse engineering 101, then. Start with `strace` - run the program with strace and see what it does to the rest of the system. Does it open network sockets? open the database file directly? etc. Also use `ldd` on it, see what libs it's actually linked to if it's not statically linked in. `nm` may tell you more about that via details of symbol versions if it isn't stripped, or you can use `strings` to search for things like the SQLite version string and informative messages.

Answer (score 2):

The official site has a pretty [comprehensive](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html) list of ways that a sqlite db can be corrupted.  Here's a brief list from that page:

1. File overwrite by a rogue thread or process
2. File locking problems
3. Failure to sync
4. Disk Drive and Flash Memory Failures
5. Memory corruption
6. Other operating system problems
7. Bugs in SQLite

One can easily imagine that a badly written program can cause `1`.